# How to set "locale" to Catalan language?

Tags: python, python-2.7, locale, setlocale

I want to change setting of `locale` in order to show titles in Catalan. To do this, I executed this command from terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED /var/lib/locales/supported.d/all
sudo locale-gen
```

In Jupyter Notebook I have this code:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ca_ES.UTF-8')
```

This is the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-4d0596ce2d84> in <module>()
     11 # sudo ln -s /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED /var/lib/locales/supported.d/all
     12 # sudo locale-gen
---> 13 locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ca_ES.UTF-8')
     14 
     15 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')

/home/ddd/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/locale.pyc in setlocale(category, locale)
    579         # convert to string
    580         locale = normalize(_build_localename(locale))
--> 581     return _setlocale(category, locale)
    582 
    583 def resetlocale(category=LC_ALL):

Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Comment: The docs show an example without the `.UTF-8`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.CHAR_MAX

Comment: @KlausD.: I tried this: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ca_ES')`, but again the same error.